# python - How create variable and set its value from data table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use a MySQL table to store attributes for report definitions.  Since each report my use different attributes, I want to store three columns - report_name, attribute, attribute_value.

I want to query the table for a report_name and get the relevant attributes and attribute_values.  I have seen in other questions that one can use

```
exec("%s = %s" % (row[0], (row[1],)))
```

to dynamically set variables names (row[0] is attribute, row[1] is attribute_value).  My problem is, the result is the resulting variables are tuples.

```
title_text = ('Daily PnL',)
```

title_text is the attribute.  'Daily PnL' is the attribute_value.

I am not able to simply say

```
exec("%s = %s" % (row[0], row[1]))
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "C:\...\test_dynamic_variables.py", line 17, in <module>  
        exec("%s = %s" % (row[0], row[1]))  
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
NameError: name 'Daily PnL' is not defined
```

Here is the larger set of code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', database='xxxx')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT attribute, attribute_value FROM reports WHERE report_name = %s")
report_name = 'Daily'

try:
    cursor.execute(query, (report_name,))
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err.msg)

row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    exec("%s = %s" % (row[0], row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

print(title_text)     #test if works
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ok.  Just figured out how to format properly.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I got your question right so please explain in a little better if my solution doesn't help you so that I can help you.

If you have

`title_text = ('Daily PnL',)`

Than try:

```
title_text = title_text[0]
```

Which converted the Tulpe to a simple string. If you than want to have both separate from each other (so 'Daily' from 'PnL') than just use the .split() method on title_text.

Comment: Not sure how I do that when I do not know in advance which attribute will be used.  The purpose of the exec() call is to create a variable name from a column in a database and then set the variable equal to the another column in the database.  How can I refer to the attribute the second time to strip the tuple down to a string?

Comment: To be clear, I do not know the variable name will be title_text until I query the MySQL table and get the two columns, attribute and attribute_value.  After that query, I would like to use the values in the attribute column to name variables then set them equal to the values in the attribute_value column.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  I need '' around the second %s as it is a string.

```
exec("%s = '%s'" % (row[0], row[1]))
```